# Best DB solution for storing large files

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, nosql

I must provide a solution where user can upload files and they must be stored together with some `metadata`, and this may grow really big.

Access to these files must be controlled, so they want me to just store them in DB `BLOB`s, but I fear `PostgreSQL` won't handle it properly over time.

My first idea was use some `NoSQL` DB solution, but I couldn't find any that would replace a good RDBMS and elegantly store files together. Then I thought on just saving these files in HD somewhere WebServer won't serve them, name them their table ID, and just load them on RAM and print them with proper content-type.

Could anyone suggest me any better solution for this?

Comment: please define "really big" - as in max file size, average file size and expected file count (or at least total size of whole data set).

Comment: Let's say PDF, ODT and other documents, received from users uploaded to WebServer. As time goes, the amount of stored files will be growing, and users wouldn't be happy if old files needed to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the requirement to store many images (with some meta data) and allow controlled access to them, here is what I did.

[To the cloud](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjtqoQE_ezA)™

I save the image files in Amazon S3. My local database holds the metadata with the S3 location of the file as one column.  When an authenticated and authorized user needs to see the file they hit a URL in my system (where the authentication and authorization checks occur) which then generates a pre-signed, expiring URL for the image and sends a redirect back to the browser. The browser is then able to load the image for a given amount of time (as specified in the signature within the URL.)

With this solution I have user level access to the resources and I don't have to store them as BLOBs or anything like that which may grow unwieldy over time. I also don't use MY bandwidth to stream the files to the client and get cheap, redundant storage for them.  Obviously the suitability of this solution will depend on the nature of the binary files you are looking to store and your level of trust in Amazon.  The world doesn't end if there is a slip and someone sees an image from my system they shouldn't. YMMV.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't store it elsewhere, it must stay in my server. I'm thinking on just opening it and printing, with some HTTP header t set its name and content-type.